# urllib2 retrieve an arbitrary file based on URL and save it into a named file

Tags: python, urllib2

I am writing a python script to use the `urllib2` module as an equivalent to the command line utility `wget`. The only function I want for this is that it can be used to retrieve an arbitrary file based on URL and save it into a named file. I also only need to worry about two command line arguments, the URL from which the file is to be downloaded and the name of the file into which the content are to be saved.

Example:

```
python Prog7.py www.python.org pythonHomePage.html
```

This is my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
#import requests

url = 'http://www.python.org/pythonHomePage.html'

print "downloading with urllib"
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "code.txt")

print "downloading with urllib2"
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()
with open("code2.txt", "wb") as code:
   code.write(data)
```

`urllib` seems to work but `urllib2` does not seem to work.

Errors received:

```
 File "Problem7.py", line 11, in <module>
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 429, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 616, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND
```

Comment: When I ran the program I recieved these errors:

Comment: File "Problem7.py", line 11, in <module>
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

Comment: Sorry the errors are above this comment.

Comment: Updated it. I am sorry, new to this forum today.

Comment: Next learning opportunity then! :-) This is not a forum; this is a *Question and Answer* site (big difference!). You ask a question, you hopefully get answers.

Comment: And you haven't specified what your expectations are here. Did you know the URL doesn't actually exist and returns a 404 for example? Did you expect the *error page* to be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the different behavior by urllib and urllib2.
Since the web page returns a 404 error (webpage not found) urllib2 "catches" it while urllib downloads the html of the returned page regardless of the error.
If you want to print the html to the text file you can print the error:

```
import urllib2
try:
    data = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/pythonHomePage.html').read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.code
    print e.msg
    print e.headers
    print e.fp.read()
    with open("code2.txt", "wb") as code:
      code.write(e.fp.read())
```

> req will be a Request object, fp will be a file-like object with the
>   HTTP error body, code will be the three-digit code of the error, msg
>   will be the user-visible explanation of the code and hdrs will be a
>   mapping object with the headers of the error.

More data about HTTP error: [urllib2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

Comment: This is a really helpful way to look at this thank you! Yes I do now see it is because of the 404 page error and that makes complete sense. Have any helpful hints on how to complete the requirements I posted above with the saving to an already existing file?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Receive arguments by using sys.argv (returns a list of arguments), accessed by sys.argv[0] for first argument, sys.argv[1] for second argument, etc. You should probably check for len(sys.argv) > 0 so you won't try to access an empty list. Don't forget to add import sys at the beginning of your code.
To "append" to a file simple use open("filename.txt",'a') like Martjin wrote above.

Comment: Okay. What would it look like if I wanted to do my command line argument above? I would need to put the "www.google.com" as one argument and then "googleHomePage.html" as another argument to make up the URL line. How can I do this?

Comment: Just concatenate the two received arguments to a string:
arg1 = sys.argv[0]
arg2 = sys.argv[1]
url = "http://" + arg1 + "/" + arg2

Comment: When I try that I keep getting this error: 

urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>

Comment: code:

import urllib2
import sys
import optparse
 
arg1 = sys.argv[0]
arg2 = sys.argv[1]

url = "http://" + arg1 + "/" + arg2

Comment: print the url variable and make sure it makes sense (maybe you are missing something in the url address).

Comment: I am so sorry to be bugging you with these questions. Good call to find out what was happening with the URL, it was wrong. Thank you for all your help, I need to test stuff more often. Thank you.

Comment: Don't worry about it, glad to help :)
In general it is always good practice to test your code, it will help you catch most bugs/code issues early. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

And the URL is doesn't exist at all; https://www.python.org/pythonHomePage.html is indeed a 404 Not Found page.

The difference between `urllib` and `urllib2` then is that the latter automatically raises an exception when a 404 page is returned, while `urllib.urlretrieve()` just saves the error page for you:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlopen('https://www.python.org/pythonHomePage.html').getcode()
404
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.urlopen('https://www.python.org/pythonHomePage.html')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND
```

If you wanted to *save* the error page, you can catch the [`urllib2.HTTPError` exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError):

```
try:
   f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
   data = f.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
   data = err.read()
```

Comment: Yes! Wow I can't believe I missed that. Tried a new page and urllib2 works for that. Would you know how to make it so that the information that urllib2 gets goes into a file that is already created in the directory? 

If I were to run the code and have it save the data in a file called "info.txt" how would I direct the data to be stored in this file?

Comment: @jbrunt13: you mean you want to *add* to `info.txt`? You'd open the file in *append mode*, use `open('info.txt', 'a')`.

Comment: YES! Append mode is what I needed, thank you so much for all your help! And the clarification on the forum and Q&A differences here. Thank you!

Comment: @jbrunt13: Glad you found both answers to be helpful :-) Note however that you can only mark *one* as accepted (most helpful). It is more than fine if you meant that to be Tom's answer, but if you tried to mark *both* then that doesn't work. Sorry!